# How should I write a flake.nix in order to use nix develop instead of nix develop github:project#shell

Tags: nix

NB: add `--extra-experimental-features nix-command --extra-experimental-features flakes` if you've allowed experimental feature in nix

This [repository](https://github.com/informalsystems/cosmos.nix) proposes to load a shell this way:

```
nix develop github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix#cosmos-shell
```

It seems to work.

In order to see if I've really understood how nix flake works (I haven't) I am trying to write a flake.nix so that I only have to write

```
nix develop
```

There is a field devShells (not devShell) in output in flake.nix in this repo. This is a collection of shells defined in `configuration.nix`.

My `flake.nix`:

```
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";  #not useful for this question
    cosmos_inform_system.url = github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix;
    flake-utils.url = github:numtide/flake-utils;
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, cosmos_inform_system, flake-utils, ... }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        shells = cosmos_inform_system.devShells;
      in {
        devShell.default = shells.cosmos-shell;
      });
}
```

```
warning: flake output attribute 'devShell' is deprecated; use 'devShells.<system>.default' instead
error: attribute 'cosmos-shell' missing
```

There is cosmos-shell in `configuration.nix` this a field `devShells`. Therefore I don't understand the error

In order to remove the warning, I replace this line

```
devShell = shells.cosmos-shell;
```

with this line:

```
devShells.${system}.default = shells.cosmos-shell;
```

> error: flake attribute 'devShell.aarch64-linux' is not a derivation

I still have the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nix flake check
```

works with that

```hs
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    cosmos_inform_system.url = github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix;
    flake-utils.url = github:numtide/flake-utils;
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, cosmos_inform_system, flake-utils, ... }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        shells = cosmos_inform_system.devShells;
      in {
        devShells.default = shells.${system}.cosmos-shell;
      }
    );
}
```

but
nix develop

> error: hash mismatch in fixed-output derivation '/nix/store/yz9kjwjhszzpp7g4wnbxj43zwga1zzsy-ica-go-modules.drv':
> specified: sha256-ykGo5TQ+MiFoeQoglflQL3x3VN2CQuyZCIiweP/c9lM=
> got:    sha256-D31e+G/7KAmF3Gkk4IOmU2g/eLlqkrkpwJa7CEjdaAk=

> [1/158 built (1 failed)] building ica-go-modules (installPhase): installing

Nevertheless I have exactly the same problem with `nix develop github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix#cosmos-shell`

I still think my flake file is the same as `nix develop github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix#cosmos-shell`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [`flake.nix`](https://github.com/informalsystems/hermes/blob/97fb4bda28ed323ddf14745a294aa1bfa0f68177/flake.nix) file for an example of how to do that.